# Number of orbits of an action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I've already showed that the map
$$\overbrace{\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\-b & a\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb Z_7\Bigg\}}^{:=G\le \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_7)}\times\overbrace{\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}:x,y\in\mathbb Z_7\Bigg\}}^{:=V}\to\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}:x,y\in\mathbb Z_7\Bigg\}\text{ such that}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\-b & a\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ax+by\\-bx+ay\end{pmatrix} $$
is an action of $G$ on $V$. The order of $G$ is $49$ (so $7^2$ and I could use the relation $|Fix_G(V)|=|V|\text{ (mod 7)}$), which is also the order of the group $V$.
I think that in order to compute the number of orbits of the action I should look at the stabilizer of a certain element in $V$.
For example amatrix $g\in G$ stabilizes an element $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\iff$
$$g\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{cases} ax+by=x\text{ (mod 7)}\\-bx+ay=y\text{ (mod 7)}\end{cases}(?)$$
but it's not so easy to solve this system. Could you help me please?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these kind of cases, it might be helpful to consider a particular element (especially if we take an element with a $0$ entry, it is even easier) and find its stabilizer. For instance, here take $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \in V$. Then, we have

$$\ \ \ \ a \equiv 1\ (\text{mod } 7) \implies a = 1\\
-b \equiv 0\ (\text{mod } 7) \implies b = 0$$

So, stabilizer of $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ consists of a single element, which is the identity of $G$. Thus, by Orbit Stabilizer Theorem, orbit of $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ consists of $49 = |V|$ elements, which means there is only $1$ orbit.

---

Of course, you might think that we were lucky here and we got a stabilizer with $1$ element so obtained the result immediately. If we try to do it by using some Number Theory, one can multiply the first congruence by $y$ and the second one by $x$ to obtain
$$\ \ \ \ axy+by^2 \equiv xy\ (\text{mod } 7)\\
\ \ \ \ axy-bx^2 \equiv xy\  (\text{mod } 7)$$
which gives us
$$b(x^2+y^2) \equiv 0\ (\text{mod } 7)$$

and we should use [Sum of two squares Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) to obtain $b = 0$ (note that $x^2+y^2 = 7$ has no integer solutions since $7 \equiv 3\ (\text{mod }4)$). Then again, the result you mentioned in comments follows.

Comment: Ok this was my idea infact. I started classifying the elements taking for example the vectors in form $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ so a matrix in $G$ stabilizes it iff $$\begin{pmatrix}ax\\-bx\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ so necessairly the matrix must have $(a,b)=(1,0)$, so there is only one element that stabilizes such an element, therefore its orbit has order $49/1=49$, but I kept thinking "I'm sure I'm doing wrong. It is too strange". Anyway, thank you for the answer!!

Comment: I added a number theoretic approach to my answer as a different approach. You may also check that one. Normally your conclusion is much easier but as a different approach, I wanted to add this to my answer. And you are welcome, good luck :)